# Cannot use Image Validation library in validation rule in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a project using Laravel 5.2. I am working with uploading images. So I need to validate image dimension. So i found a library, https://github.com/cviebrock/image-validator . So I installed that library as follow using composer.

I run this command in terminal:

```
composer require "cviebrock/image-validator:^2.0"
```

So this is auto-added to my `composer require`:

```
"cviebrock/image-validator": "^2.0"
```

Then I added this to provider section in config/app.php

```
Cviebrock\ImageValidator\ImageValidatorServiceProvider::class
```

Then I validate like this in controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'imge_file'=>'image|image_size:300,300',
        ]);
```

But validation never fails even I upload image with invalid dimension. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you mean for the file name to be image_file?

Answer (score 1):

Make the rule required.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'imge_file'=>'required|image|image_size:300,300',
    ]);
```

Comment: When I add required. It keep saying image is required even if I uploaded an image. Please why ?

Comment: You'll need to add more code for us to see what's going on. Is your image named 'imge_file' in the html?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the uploaded image to be **exactly** 300x300 or do you want any image less than or equal to those dimensions?

Currently, you are checking for images exactly 300x300.

Change the rule to: `image|image_size:<=300` to allow any images less than or equal to 300x300.

Comment: I want it exactly 300*300

Comment: @WaiYanHein `dd()` the `$request` and make sure the image field is there.

Comment: Opps. I found the error. File filed is not presented in dd() even if it does exists in the form. I changed to image_file from imge_file in validation rule. That was totally my fault. But thanks to you suggestion. That is why I found this error and it is the new  thing I know.

Comment: I thought it might be the typo. Glad I could help!